# Android SDK not found in react-native doctor

Tags: android, react-native, sdk

I have a problem configuring Android SDK in ubuntu 20. Command npx react-native doctor does not find Android SDK.

```
This is my $PATH :
/home/77milions/.nvm/versions/node/v18.13.0/bin:
/home/77milions/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:
/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin:
/home/77milions/Android/Sdk/emulator:
/home/77milions/Android/Sdk/tools:
/home/77milions/Android/Sdk/tools/bin:
/home/77milions/Android/Sdk/platform-tools:
/home/77milions/Android/Sdk/cmdline-tools/latest/bin`

These are exports inside ~/.bashrc file: 
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/latest/bin
```

My only SDK Platform installed  in Android studio is :
Android 13.0 ("Tiramisu"), Version:33, revision: 2

Android SDK Location inside Android Studio settings is set to:  /home/77milions/Android/Sdk

I have installed Android SDK Build-Tools 34 , Android SDK Command-line Tools(latest), Android Emulator and Android SKD Platform tools  in Android SDK Tools tab.

Nothing seems to work. Maybe I should downgrade Android Studio to a older version ?
My current Android Studio version is : Giraffe 2023.3.1

When I try to run sdkmanager file that is located in:
/home/77milions/Android/Sdk/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager i get this error :

```
error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class  
com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/sdklib/tool/sdkmanager/SdkManagerCli has been 
compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of 
the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0
```

Any help or hints appreciated.

Thanks.

I tried changing paths, exports in Ubuntu, different Emulator versions and lots of other tweakings.

Comment: Try the below answer might help you for linux. [Android SDK issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032501/android-sdk-unable-to-run-the-sdk-manager)